# Apache web server is already running

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I can't start apache because I have this error  "Apache web server is already running".

I go this code `"sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start"`
and I obtain:

```
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

have just done:

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2
```

But it doesn't resolve  my problem. I modify apache port at 81. Anyone can  help me?

Comment: Have you tried easily `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop` and than `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`?

Comment: @janfitz yess the error appears again. No change

Comment: Try this in terminal `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop` and than `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`

Comment: I have done sudo apt-get remove apache2

Comment: I resolve thank to this http://askubuntu.com/questions/89156/cannot-start-xampp-on-ubuntu-11-10

Answer (score 2):

This work for me

on command line,

`ps ax | grep httpd`

and

`kill -9 [PID]`

`sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart`

Answer (score 1):

> > > Try this.....

```
   $sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop  
   $sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop  (may be failed, don't worry, move further)
   $sudo /etc/init.d/proftpd stop
```